# How to subtract two date columns and the result being a positive integer only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

```
    Employee ID Name    Leave From  Leave To     Leave Days
    10107       Habib   2020-10-31  2020-01-11   -293 days +00:00:00
```

I want to extract the total no. of leave days for every employee by subtracting Leave To column from Leave From column. This works well for most of the cases and returns a positive result. But there are certain records for which the result turns out to be negative and absurd and a very large integer. How should I  cater such dates where the date value for Leave To column is less than the date value of Leave From column. As the issue persists for these type of rows only.

Comment: You can use `np.where` compare dates and if true assign value for that row

Comment: Can you further elaborate this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `clip`:

```
df['Leave Day'] = df['Leave To'].sub(df['Leave From']).clip(0)
```

Comment: UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'greater_equal' input 0 from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
df['Leave From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Leave From'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df['Leave To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Leave To'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df['Leave Days'] = np.where(df['Leave To']<df['Leave From'], 0, (df['Leave To']-df['Leave From']).dt.days)
```

Comment: This works but I don't want the result to be zero for such cases as there would be absurd results then which can not be compromised on. Any other way without making such entries zero?

Comment: @HammadMalick You can provide custom values may be give nan values

Comment: Null values will be miore hard to tackle.

Comment: @HammadMalick: I don't know what are you trying to do  but the logic will be like this. If you need pandas frndly solution follow Quang Hong answer.